# Is it worth storing the result of a function call in a temp variable for further reuse in this case?

Tags: c++, performance, optimization

```
std::rotate(vec.begin(), vec.begin() + index, vec.begin() + index + 1);
```

```
auto first = vec.begin();
auto toMove = first + index;
std::rotate(first, toMove, toMove + 1);
```

Will the second version be more efficient than the first? Can the compiler implicitly optimize the first version to avoid multiple calls to `vec.begin()`?

Comment: AFAIK, a local variable with small values (e.g. integrals, pointers, references, etc.) never hurts. The compiler will (hopefully) optimize away what's unnecessary. On the other hand, if the called function is an inline just returning a member of something (what's usually called a "getter") this is probably optimized by the compiler as well. So, don't think too much about this until you identify it as the "real" bottleneck. Just write the code that it becomes best readable. (If in doubt, you still can compare the two versions in Compiler Explorer...)

Comment: Just to give an example: Yesterday, I was about to complain that (for `double x;`) `x * x` is better than `pow(x, 2)`. Of course, `pow()` is a terrible function and multiplication is probably faster. However, I was surprised that `g++` yielded the exact same multiplication commands for both versions. I hadn't expected that the compiler is _that_ clever. (Or somebody foresaw the issue and made a resp. tweak in the std lib. - I don't know. I just was impressed.) :-)

Comment: This is a low level optimization question that you should not worry unless profiling proves that that specific code requires it. If you are still in early development, you should only worry for correctness and readability. The hard point with low level optimization it that the best code depends on the compiler and compilation option, so there is generaly no generic answer.

Comment: I understand, this is a matter of opinion, but which approach do you consider to be more readable? Which of them would you use yourself?

Comment: @Alexey104 Note that such questions are off-topic on Stack Overflow; however, as for myself, I would definitely prefer the first option.

Comment: I'll suggest second one while combining L1 and L3 for readability, but it's just an opinion.

Comment: Sorry for the off-topic, and thank you all for the answers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only possible answer is "it depends". On what? On the implementation of involved iterators.

For instance, with `std::vector`, I got the very same generated machine code for both options. This is because vector iterators are basically just pointers to vector value types, possibly wrapped into some implementation class. It is then easy for a compiler to resolve optimizations on operations with such a "basic" type.

Live demo: https://godbolt.org/z/srxcrbaqf

On the contrary, with `std::deque`, I got the different machine code for both options. And, it seems to be more efficient for the second one. At least, it was shorter, having 89 assembly lines in contrast to 115. The reason is that deque does not store elements contiguously in memory, so its iterators need to be implemented in a more complex object-oriented way. And, this might in practice hinder optimizations.

Live demo: https://godbolt.org/z/1oqjzMerv

BTW, in my experiment with libstdc++, vector iterator was even a *trivially-copyable* type, while deque iterator was not: https://godbolt.org/z/GfqhaaaYM.